# Unity3d Transform View Frustum

Tags: matrix, unity-game-engine, view, frustum

How do I transform a Unity3d camera's view frustum so that I can pass in a Plane and have the camera's near clipping plane become that plane? The plane might not be perpendicular to the looking direction. I am not familiar with the Matrix4x4.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UAcB.png)

I am not interested in a solution involving applying a material with a custom shader to every object in my scene.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why the limitation against shader-based solutions? That really does seem like the way to go, here. You could use camera pre-render hooks to cull entire objects, but that doesn't quite match the behavior you're asking for.

Comment: If I wanted to use multiple materials and shaders in my scene, I'd have to program a clipping plane into every shader. I know how to do that- I'm just hoping there's an easier way.